# How to get href Text using CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I have the following HTML below from Wikipedia main page at https://www.wikipedia.org/. I'm trying to get the href text

`//en.wikipedia.org/`

```
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
<a href="//en.wikipedia.org/" title="English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia" class="link-box">
<strong>English</strong><br>
<em>The Free Encyclopedia</em><br>
<small>5&nbsp;077&nbsp;000+ articles</small>
</a>
</div>
```

I've tried this `$$('.central-featured-lang.lang1 a[href$=".org/"]')` but I still get the whole output, not just the href text.

```
[<a href=​"/​/​en.wikipedia.org/​" title=​"English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia" class=​"link-box">​…​</a>​<strong>​English​</strong>​<br>​<em>​The Free Encyclopedia​</em>​<br>​<small>​5&nbsp;077&nbsp;000+ articles​</small>​</a>​]
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

[image: Error Message Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript you can use **[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** along with `href` attribute, like this:

```js
var url = document.querySelector('.central-featured-lang.lang1 a[href$=".org/"]').href;
alert(url);
```

```html
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
  <a href="//en.wikipedia.org/" title="English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia" class="link-box">
    <strong>English</strong>
    <br>
    <em>The Free Encyclopedia</em>
    <br>
    <small>5&nbsp;077&nbsp;000+ articles</small>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. worked perfectly. Although, I tried this and it worked too. 
`var url = document.querySelector('.central-featured-lang.lang1 a').href;`
Would this be the better option?

Comment: @Ming, this second selector is getting all link elements inside your div, while the first one is getting only links that their href finishs with `".org/"`, that's the only difference. But here as you are only one link they will give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`.attr()` Method:](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.central-featured-lang.lang1 a[href$=".org/"]').attr("href")
```

```js
var url = $('.central-featured-lang.lang1 a[href$=".org/"]').attr("href");
alert( url );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
<a href="//en.wikipedia.org/" title="English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia" class="link-box">
<strong>English</strong><br>
<em>The Free Encyclopedia</em><br>
<small>5&nbsp;077&nbsp;000+ articles</small>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried in my Chrome console. But I get the error 
`VM243:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM243:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM99:878InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM99:811InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM99:667 `

I've attached the error message screenshot in the post

Comment: I just noticed that this is using jquery. Does it mean I have to import jquery into all my scripts. Would it be less complicated to do it in native css selector js. Thank you very much for advise.
How do i import Jquery in Chrome console.

Answer (score 2):

Use DOM Element [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) Method

> *getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned
>   will either be null or "" (the empty string); see Notes for details.*

```js
var element = document.querySelector('a.link-box'),
       link = element.getAttribute('href');

alert(link)
```

```html
<div class="central-featured-lang lang1" lang="en">
  <a href="//en.wikipedia.org/" title="English — Wikipedia — The Free Encyclopedia" class="link-box">
    <strong>English</strong>
    <br>
    <em>The Free Encyclopedia</em>
    <br>
    <small>5&nbsp;077&nbsp;000+ articles</small>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works to but @chsdk was more concise. 
Tried your code. Could have been done in this. 
`var element = document.querySelector('a.link-box').href;`
I've upvoted your answer too.